# Merge two arrays without an element in php

Tags: php, arrays, web

I have two associative arrays, and I need to merge it into one array, **without** an element from first array.
Now it looks like that:

```
$result = array_merge(getFirstArray(), getSecondArray());
```

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Please provide an example showing your arrays, and explain what element from the first array you don't want

Comment: First get out the element, what you do not want in your array with `array_filter` or by looping through it and `unset` and then you can merge.

Comment: public function getFirstArray() {
    return array(
               'element1' => 'description',
               'element2' => 'description');
}
And getSecondArray() the simular

Answer (score 0):

> and I need to merge it into one array, without an element from first array.

Then remove it. Before or after merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the element in the first array and you know which one it is, then just remove it before the merge:

```
$array1 = getFirstArray();
unset($array1['element1']); // or $array1[0] or whatever the index is;
$result = array_merge($array1, getSecondArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_filter(getFirstArray(),
                   array_merge(getFirstArray(), getSecondArray());
```